# How to pass "a pointer to a function with parameters" to another function

Tags: c

I have the following system function:

```
int sock_yield( void *s, void (*fn)() );
```

to which I need to pass a function that takes 2 parameters:

```
void reset(char buf,udp_Socket sock) {

    if (-1 == udp_recv(&sock, &buf, sizeof(buf)));

    if(buf=='R')
    {

        printf("\nReceived-> %c",buf);

        forceSoftReset();

        forceWatchdogTimeout();

    }

}
```

When calling `sock_yield` function I can only pass it the name of the function without its parameter:
`sock_yield(sock, reset)`

How to specify the parameters of `reset` to be passed to `sock_yield`?

Comment: please format the code according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You don't. How does `sock_yield` invoke `fn`?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this. Converting between different function types is strictly speaking undefined behavior, although some compilers have non-standard extensions that allow it at some extent.

In addition, `void (*fn)()` means a function taking any parameters, which is obsolete style C and shouldn't be used.

So the `sock_yield` function must be rewritten. If it was meant to take a callback function as parameter, it was badly written from the start. It should take function pointers of one specific, specified format. For example:

```
typedef void sock_callback_t (char buf, udp_socket* sock);

int sock_yield(void* s, sock_callback_t* fn);
```

Alterntatively you could write some hack where you convert between function pointers and `uintptr_t`, but it is a worse solution that should only be used if you are stuck with a badly written API.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. C only knows raw pointer to functions. You can then give all the required parameters when you use the pointer. Example:

```
int double(int i) {
    return 2*1;
}

int exec_op(int param, int (*op)()) {
   return op(param);
}
```

This works because in C a void parameter list means that the function can accept any parameters.

If in your use case `sock_yield` calls the function without parameters, the only option is to use a wrapper using global parameters:

```
char Buf;
udp_Socket Sock;

void reset_wrapper(void) {
    reset(Buf, Sock);
}
```

and later use it that way:

```
    Buf = buf;
    Sock = sock;
    sock_yield(s, &reset_wrapper);
```